# Remove button in p:selectOneMenu

Tags: jsf, primefaces, selectonemenu

Well, I want to do something like this with PrimeFaces, but I don't know how to put a button side by side with my `<f:selectItems>` to remove that item.

[image: Selectonemenu with a remove button in every selectitems]

```
<p:selectOneMenu id="pesquisaSalva"
                 rendered="#{!mapaEleitoralControl.desabiliarRadioPesquisaSalva}"
                 disabled="#{mapaEleitoralControl.desabiliarRadioPesquisaSalva}"
                 value="#{mapaEleitoralControl.parametrosPesquisaSalva}"
                 var="teste">

    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Selecione a pesquisa salva"
                  itemValue=""
                  noSelectionOption="true" />

    <f:selectItems value="#{mapaEleitoralControl.listaPesquisaSalvasMapaEleitoral}"
                   var="pesquisaSalvaME"
                   itemValue="#{pesquisaSalvaME.anoEleicao}"
                   itemLabel="#{pesquisaSalvaME.anoEleicao}"/>

    <p:column>
        #{teste}
    </p:column>

    <p:column>
        <p:commandButton id="iconOnly" icon="ui-icon-trash" title="Icon Only" />
    </p:column>

    <p:ajax event="change"
            update="mapaEleitoralForm"
            global="false"
            listener="#{mapaEleitoralControl.selectPesquisaSalvaGerarMapa}" />
</p:selectOneMenu>
```

Comment: Aren't that text on the left and the dust bin on the right in the given picture lined up correctly? They appear to stand side by side correctly.

Comment: Yes, they are, that picture is just to illustrate what I want to do.

Comment: Except for `<p:selectManyMenu>`, I never tried a `<p:column>` inside a `<p:selectOneMenu>`. Does that `<p:column>` inside the given `<p:selectOneMenu>` work? Did you try it in your real code?

Comment: I did, but didn't work so I don't know what to do

Comment: According to [this](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/input/oneMenu.xhtml) showcase example, `<p:column>`s are allowed in a `<p:selectOneMenu>`. See the advanced option on that page.

Comment: I kwon that, that is why i tried with no success hahaha

Comment: A `<p:selectOneMenu>` using `<p:column>`s just renders an HTML table. It should not then be hard to produce a layout in a format of your choice. Isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

I had to solve the same problem. I did it this way (there might be better ways).

```
    <p:selectOneMenu styleClass="bookMarkMenu" id="bookmarkMenu" value="#{bean.bookmark}" var="bookmark" style="width:150px;" converter="#{entityConverter}" panelStyle="width:300px;">
                            <f:selectItem itemLabel="#{messages['bookmark.select']}" itemVaule=""/>
                            <f:selectItems value="#{bean.bookmarks}" var="b" itemLabel="#{b.description}" itemValue="#{b}"/>
                            <p:column style="width:100px;">
                                <h:outputText style="padding-left:8px;" value="#{bookmark.description}" rendered="#{bookmark ne null}"/>
                            </p:column>
<p:column style="width:15px; padding:0px;">
                            <p:commandLink style="padding: 4px 10px 4px 10px;"  onclick="deleteCalled(event,#{bookmark.bookmarkId});"><i class="fa fa-trash-o" aria-hidden="true"></i></p:commandLink>
                        </p:column>

                        <p:ajax event="itemSelect" listener="#{bean.onBookmarkSelect}"/>
                    </p:selectOneMenu>
```

The problem with adding a p:commandLink (or button) in one of the p:columns is that the listener for the item selection will still be called. Thats why I call the javascript method deleteCalled onclick.

```
<p:remoteCommand name="deleteBookmark" action="#{bean.deleteBookmark()}" update="#{p:component('bookmarkDec')}"/>

    <script>
        function deleteCalled(event,id){
            event.stopPropagation();
            if(confirm('Do you really want to delete the bookmark?')){
                deleteBookmark([{name:'bookmarkId',value: id}]);
            }
            return false;
        }

    </script>
```

In that javascript method you need to stop the event propagation and then call a p:remoteCommand. In this case I've passed the ID of the bookmark (my items in the list).

Hope that helps.